# Number of linear extensions of $\mathbb{P}([n])$ partially ordered by inclusion

Tags: combinatorics

A linear extension of $\mathbb{P}([n])$, i.e. all subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ is a total ordering of all the subsets where $A < B$ in the ordering if $A \subset B$. If $n=2$ the number of linear extensions is $2$, and if $n=3$ the number of linear extensions of $48$. What is the number of linear extensions for general $n$? If this is too hard, what about $n=4$ and possibly $n=5$? Is there a systematic counting argument strategy? Or better yet, a recursion generating the sequence for arbitrary $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fantastic resource for these sorts of questions (you have a few terms of a sequence and a few keywords, and want to know more about it) is the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/).  Doing a search there for "2,48 extensions" gives 4 results, of which the [third (A046873)](http://oeis.org/A046873) is exactly the sequence you want.

That result includes values for $n=4 (1680384)$ and $n=5 (14807804035657359360)$, along with some references to papers describing the rough asymptotics of your sequence (from Brightwell and Tetali's paper the log base $2$ of the number of extensions grows like 
$$2^t\left(\binom{t}{t/2}-\frac{3}{2} \log_2 e +o(1)\right)$$
as $t$ tends to infinity).  From the comments in the OEIS entry, even computing the $n=6$ term required a substantial computational effort, so I suspect no nice recurrence/strategy is known.